# Ignore platform reqs in Zend studio composer when installing dependencies

Tags: heroku, composer-php, zend-studio

In Zend studio how can I set composer to ignore platform reqs as I need to add PHP so extensions to my composer file for the heroku dependencies but don't want to install them on my local machine as all development and testing is done through heroku.

Comment: Did you tried `--ignore-platform-reqs` switch for `composer install` command?

Comment: That's the switch I want to use but in my system composer gets launched by a button from within Zend Studio so trying to figure out how to do it from there